# How can I return a boolean field for whether the current server time is in between two date fields in a MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

For each business I'm currently storing a MongoDB date for the opening and closing time on each week day. I'm storing this date as `0001-01-01T09:00:00.000Z` for example because I don't want a year, month, and day associated with the time, I just want the time.

This aggregation currently correctly returns the opening and closing time for the current day as a string formatted like `09:00`, but I also want to return a boolean field 'isOpen' which returns true or false for if the business is currently open based on the system time, and the opening and closing time of the current day.

I'm currently struggling to find a way to do this.

```
exports = async ({ limit, lat, lng, maxDistance }) => {
      const METERS_PER_MILE = 1609.34
      const cluster = context.services.get('mongodb-atlas');
      const organizationsCollection = cluster.db('Cheers-Development').collection('organizations');
    
      const organizations = await organizationsCollection.aggregate(
        [
          {
            $geoNear: {
              near: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [lat, lng]
              }, 
              maxDistance: maxDistance * METERS_PER_MILE,
              spherical: true,
              distanceField: 'distance',
              distanceMultiplier: 0.000621371
            }
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'categories',
              localField: 'categoryIds',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'categories'
            }
          },
          {
            $addFields: {
              openingTime: {
                $switch: {
                  branches: [
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 1] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.sunday.openingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 2] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.monday.openingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 3] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.tuesday.openingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 4] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.wednesday.openingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 5] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.thursday.openingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 6] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.friday.openingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 7] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.saturday.openingTime" } }
                    }
                  ],
                  default: null,
                }
              },
              closingTime: {
                $switch: {
                  branches: [
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 1] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.sunday.closingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 2] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.monday.closingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 3] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.tuesday.closingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 4] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.wednesday.closingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 5] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.thursday.closingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 6] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.friday.closingTime" } }
                    },
                    {
                      case: { $eq: [{ $dayOfWeek: "$$NOW" }, 7] },
                      then: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M", date: "$openingTimes.saturday.closingTime" } }
                    }
                  ],
                  default: null,
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $addFields: {
              isOpen: 'Is the business currently open?'
            }
          }
        ] 
      ).toArray();
      
      return organizations;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      today: "friday",
      currentTime: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          "year": 1, "month": 1, "day": 1,
          "hour": { $hour: "$$NOW" },
          "minute": { $minute: "$$NOW" },
          "second": { $second: "$$NOW" },          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $set: { openingTimes: { "$objectToArray": "$openingTimes" } } },
  {
    $set: {
      openingTimes: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$openingTimes",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.k", "$today" ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      isOpen: {
        $and: [
          { $gte: [ "$openingTimes.v.openingTime", "$currentTime" ] },
          { $lt: [ "$openingTimes.v.closingTime", "$currentTime" ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YTqbdWvd0kb)

Getting the weekday is not so easy (unless you do a `$switch` with 7 branches), I would suggest [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library, then it would be simply `today: moment().format("ddd")` or directly `cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.k", moment().format("ddd") ] }`